# How to ad an effect to an ImageButton on an android app?

Tags: android, eclipse, button, indentation, effect

I currently added two ImageButtons on my android application project, but when I press then on my android device, there is no effect that the button gets indented. How can I put an effect to it so it looks more like a button when it's pressed?

My full source code looks something like this:

```
    final TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    text2.setText("");
    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText("");
    final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            clicked1 = 0;
            clicked2 = 0;
            text2.setText("  " + clicked1 + " SHOTS ");
            text.setText("  " + clicked2 + " CUPS ");
        }
    });

    final TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    text1.setText("  0 SHOTS");
    final ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            clicked2++;
            text1.setText("  " + clicked2 + " SHOTS ");
        }
    });
    final TextView text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text3.setText("  0 CUPS");
    final ImageButton button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            clicked1++;
            text3.setText("  " + clicked1 + " CUPS ");

        }


    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can do this,very easily,lets try using simple button on place of your ImageButtons and do following

---

Create an xml file and save it in one of the `drawable` folders in your project,let `bg.xml`,set this one as the background of your **Button**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_notpressed" />
</selector>
```

where **button_pressed** and **button_notpressed** are the images which you want to show on transition of the clicks and normal view of button

In your activity's **xml** file,set the background of the button as `bg.xml`

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"  <--! set it like this-->
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```